# Extract SQL Query with JSON - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have a table called country_zones and theres a column called country which currently holds

["canada","United States"]

I first, extract the users country they signed up with and then need to do a query to see which users country matches the row of country_zones. Although whenever I do that I either get error or NULL

Ive tried this.

```
  $country = json_decode($this->db->get_where('country_zones',array('country'=>$user_country)));
```

also.

```
$country = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country_zones WHERE country='$user_country'")->result();
```

Comment: And what do you get from your attempts?

Comment: Show more of the code as what you show is not of much help to us

Comment: what is dataType for country column? and share $user_country value?

Comment: Datatype is LongText, and I just have a query to extract users country aka, It displays 'Canada' thats what '$user_country' holds. Now I need to find the row in the country_zones table which holds 'canada' and return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say user_country is Canada, then your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM country_zones WHERE country LIKE '%"Canada"%';
```

So, try this:

```
$country = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country_zones WHERE country LIKE '%\"$user_country\"%'")->result();
```

**Edit:**

`LIKE` query is needed because column contains `["canada","United States"]` and you want to match it with `Canada`. So above LIKE query is SQL way of saying give me rows where country contains "Canada".

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: It works! Can you just explain to me why I need to use LIKE and what the '%\ is for??

Comment: Thank you. And now if I want to extract just the country row can I do $thecountry = $country->row()->country; ??

Comment: What do you mean by "extract just the country row"? Also, PHP is not my forte, I can help with MySQL though.